# Veracrypt options disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, asus-laptop, veracrypt

I would like to encrypt my whole computer with Veracrypt, but when I try to, the buttons are hidden :

I want a normal system encryption, but the whole drive too, which is impossible here.
I tried to uninstall VeraCrypt, install it again, reboot my computer but it hasn't worked.

[image: Type of System Encryption : Normal or Hidden]

[image: Encrypt the whole drive or encrypt the windows system partition]

Also, if this finally work, I was planning to take Twofish Serpent encryption algorithm and SHA-512 hash algorithm.

Do you think it's a good choice ?

Thanks

Comment: I think Bitlocker is a much better choice if your Windows supports it.

Comment: I would love having Bitlock, but unfortunally it is only available on Windows 10 Pro...

Comment: I disagree that bitlocker is any better.

Comment: @Overmind Maybe it has a handy feature, just in case you "forget" your passphrase maybe someone at MS can decrypt your files for you? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot encrypt the whole volume because you have secureboot enabled or you use some other type of encryption that interferes with the boot loading.

Disable secure boot, set your UEFI in BIOS-compatible mode, install the OS and then you can use whole drive encryption.

If you do need to boot from a partition larger than 2TB then you do need to leave GPT/UEFI boot on, but if not, there is no reason not to use MBR.

Comment: VeraCrypt supports GPT what’s the point of enabling compatibility mode?

Comment: Why use GPT for a boot drive ? GPT is for 2TB+ drives. I don't know many booting from 2TB+ partitions. BIOS-compatible mode does not prevent you from using GPT disks inside the OS.

Comment: All my devices have 4TB+ storage devices.  If you enable CPM, it means you end up using MBR, instead of GPT.

Comment: Not exactly. Do not confuse booting with drive mode support. Using a MBR boot device does not prevent you from using GPT drives inside the OS. My current setups are 64GB SSD MBR boot encrypted OS with RAID single partition 5.54 TB GPT and the notebook is 256 SSD MBR Encrypted boot device with 3.63TB GPT drive (which has the encrypted file container). Now if you want to boot from 2TB+ devices then you do indeed need GPT enabled via UEFI to do that. Not needing to to that I see no need not to use MBR for the OS boot drive. I added the last part to the answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: There are disadvantages to using MBR in 2018.  I am not confusing anything.